# jQuery build table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

`menuOrder` is an empty div

```
$("#menuOrder").append('<table>');

$(menus).each(function(i, menu) {
  $("#menuOrder").append('<tr><td>');
  $("#menuOrder").append(menu.text);
  $("#menuOrder").append('</td><td>');

  if (i > 0) {
    $("#menuOrder").append('<img src="/images/_images/up.png" />');
  } else {
    $("#menuOrder").append('<img src="/images/_images/blank.png" />');
  }

  if (i < menus.length - 1) {
    $("#menuOrder").append('<img src="/images/_images/down.png" />');
  }

  $("#menuOrder").append('</td>');
  $("#menuOrder").append('</tr>');
});

$("#menuOrder").append('</table>');
```

this code not work properly, how can I change it with minimum iterations?

Comment: It is recommend to avoid lots of .append like this, instead when possible, build the string with HTML and then append

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing something like this:

```
var rows = [];
$(menus).each(function(i, menu) {
 var row = '<tr><td>'.menu.text.'</td><td>';

    if (i > 0) {
        row +='<img src="/images/_images/up.png" />';
    }
    else {
        row +='<img src="/images/_images/blank.png" />';
    }

    if (i < menus.length - 1) {
       row +='<img src="/images/_images/down.png" />';
    }

    row += '</td></tr>';
    rows.push(row);
});
$('<table></table>').append(rows.join('')).appendTo('#menuOrder');
```

This fills the `rows` array with a string that contains the HTML for each row.  When its done creating all the rows then it creates a jQuery Object of a table element and appends all the rows to it.  It then appends the table to `#menuOrder`.

Comment: I'd also mention that it is better to add all rows at once, storing html for them in a single string. some browsers has issues while manipulating parts of table's inner html

Answer (score 1):

Note that with `append()` you can't do this:

```
$("#menuOrder").append('</table>');
```

Instead of glueing together pieces of HTML strings, you must think in terms of complete DOM nodes. Examples of valid arguments for `append()`:

```
.append($('.something'))
.append(document.createElement('div'))
.append('<div />') // automatically creates empty div element
.append('<tr><td></td></tr>') // automatically creates tr with td inside
```